# How to do this complicated thing with mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, string, apache, .htaccess, web-services

I'm hopeless when it comes to regex and/or the RewriteEngine, so my hours of researching and trying things have been pretty fruitless so far.

I'm trying to use the RewriteEngine to accomplish behavior that will follow these rules:

If the requested URL...

- ...points to an existing file **e.g.** `domain.com/existing_file.ext`

  - do no rewrites
- ...is empty, or contains only trailing slash(es) **e.g.** `domain.com/`

  - rewrite to `index.php?var=example`
- ...points to an existing directory that is not root (with or without trailing slashes) **e.g.** `domain.com/existing_directory`

  - rewrite to `index.php?var=REQUESTED_DIRECTORY_PATH/example` where `REQUESTED_DIRECTORY_PATH` is everything after `domain.com` (preferably always without a trailing slash)
- ...is not empty, but doesn't point to an existing file or directory **e.g.** `domain.com/no_such_file_or_directory`

  - rewrite to `index.php?var=REQUESTED_URL`, where `REQUESTED_URL` is everything after `domain.com`

---

This is what I've got so far:

```
# /
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?var=example [QSA,L]

# /directory_name/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /index.php?var=$0/example [QSA,L]

# /not_a_valid_file_or_dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?var=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Which to me seems to almost do what I want, except for when I try to access `domain.com/existing_directory` (with or without a trailing slash). In this case I get redirected to `domain.com/existing_directory/` (with a slash), while I would like to be end up at `domain.com/index.php?var=existing_directory/example`.

Comment: Are you wanting the URL to actually change from `/blah` to `/index.php?var=blah`?

Comment: @Bananaapple No, the URL should be displayed as `/blah`, while the internal request should be `/index.php?var=blah`.

Comment: There is nothing in your sample htaccess code that would result in the behaviour your describe - that is redirect from `/existing_directory` to `/existing_directory/`. Are there other instructions in the htaccess file?

Comment: No, I just had `RewriteEngine on` and `RewriteBase /`. I did a bit of Googling, and found a `mod_dir` option `DirectorySlash`, which by default adds a slash to urls that point to valid directories without a trailing slash. I turned it off, and now `/existing_dir` (without trailing slash) correctly points to `/index.php?var=existing_dir/example`. And after removing the `[^/]` from the regex, now `/existing_dir/` correctly points to the same place, too. If you want to add an answer detailing those changes, I'll gladly accept it. Or I could submit my own answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well you figured it out so probably best to answer yourself :D

Comment: Alright, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to helpful comments from Bananaapple, and a bit of Googling, I managed to accomplish what I wanted.

Firstly, I had to turn `DirectorySlash off`, and secondly I needed to remove the `[^/]` from the regex. So the final relevant code would look something like this:

```
DirectorySlash Off

# /
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?var=example [QSA,L]

# /directory_name/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?var=$0/example [QSA,L]

# /not_a_valid_file_or_dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?var=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks for the help.